# How to set child forms focus on taskbar button click?

Tags: delphi, callback, taskbar, mouseclick-event, window-managers

I am using Delphi XE 2010 on Windows 7. I need to be able to set focus and bring the child form(s) to the front of other child forms only not for the whole program or application, when you left click on the taskbar button.

So, I need to know how you write your callback procedure for that. I tried WM_LEFTBUTTONUP, but it seems to be reacting for the whole application instead of just the child form.

This is all I have right now. Procedure definition is not complete for I am currently investigating what sort of messages it receives and all.

```
procedure WMnclb(var Msg:TMessage) ; message WM_NCLBUTTONUP;

procedure TViewFrm.WMnclb(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if Msg.LParam<0 then
    Msg.LParam:=0;
end;
```

Any help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `WM_NCLBUTTONUP` message instead of `WM_LEFTBUTTONUP`.

Comment: If you need further help, please show some code.